# How to split a stacktrace line into namespace, class, method file and line number?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, stack-trace

C# stack traces take the following form:

```
   at Foo.Core.Test.FinalMethod(Doh doh) in C:\Projects\src\Core.Tests\Test.cs:line 21
   at Foo.Core.Test.AnotherMethod(Bar bar)
   at Foo.Core.Test.AMethod() in C:\Projects\src\Core.Tests\Test.cs:line 6
   at Foo.Core.Test.<>c__DisplayClass7.<SomeAnonDelegate>b__6(Object _) in C:\Projects\src\Core.Tests\Test.cs:line 35
```

How can I retrieve namespace, class, method, file and line number from each line?

- Are there any existing classes to do this?
- If not what would be the the best approach?
- Regex?  How would I greedily match the namespace but leave the class and method?
- Custom parser?

Would appreciate some ideas and input.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, to you intend to use this in a production environment? As far as i remember, the stack-trace isn't included in release mode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx which states that all these information are obtained from the debug symbols, which aren't included in the release builder per default.

Comment: @J. Tihon, good point, however we include symbol information in our Release builds

Comment: Well, I just didn't want you to go through all the trouble with regex and all, when you can't really use it at the end.

Comment: @J. Tihon: Stack traces do emanate from release builds even without symbols, but they are missing line numbers and filenames.

Comment: There is very little reason not to ship your symbols when deploying. PDBs do not cause notable performance degradation (it is a common misconception that they are related to debug builds).

Comment: can you put full code for parsing StackTrace string value from an exception?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're getting this from a [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx), then you can loop through the [StackFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx) via [GetFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe.aspx) and call [GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod.aspx), [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilename.aspx), and [GetFileLineNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilelinenumber.aspx).  Namespace and class can be retrieved from the method.

**EDIT**
In response to the first comment (*unfortunately we get the traces from Exception.StackTrace*), you can call the [StackTrace(Exception)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25h0kw08.aspx) constructor.

**EDIT**
I should've linked to this constructor instead -- [StackTrace(Exception,bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt.aspx).

Comment: `Exception.StackTrace` is a `string`, which **cannot be passed into the constructor** of `StackTrace` (it doesn't take a `string`).

Comment: @adrianbanks:  That is indeed true and while OP said that he got it from `Exception.StackTrace`, there was nothing stating he doesn't have access to the Exception object (+1 for your comment BTW).

Comment: Fortunately I do have access to Exception so this is a good solution. Unfortunately it won't provide file, line# and column# but I think I can probably live without that.

Comment: I take that back, there is an overload which will provide file info also.

Comment: This doesn't work in PCL. One also has to think about localization if parsing the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

I read the Austin Salonen's answer and it's obvious better, but I've already started with regex. so I'll write it anyway.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"at (?<namespace>.*)\.(?<class>.*)\.(?<method>.*(.*)) in (?<file>.*):line (?<line>\d*)");
var result = r.Match(@"at Foo.Core.Test.FinalMethod(Doh doh) in C:\Projects\src\Core.Tests\Test.cs:line 21");
if (result.Success)
{
    string _namespace = result.Groups["namespace"].Value.ToString();
    string _class = result.Groups["class"].Value.ToString();
    string _method = result.Groups["method"].Value.ToString();
    string _file = result.Groups["file"].Value.ToString();
    string _line = result.Groups["line"].Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("namespace: " + _namespace);
    Console.WriteLine("class: " + _class);
    Console.WriteLine("method: " + _method);
    Console.WriteLine("file: " + _file);
    Console.WriteLine("line: " + _line);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I'm glad you posted anyway as you reminded me that C# allows named matches. Out of interest will the namespace match cope with nested namespaces e.g. Ns1.Ns2.Ns3.Class.Method?

Comment: Yes it will, try it. but seems I have a problem when the string doesn't contains all the parts, I mean `in` and the path.

Comment: What if you run this program in Germany with localized .NET runtime?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: You're right. But I've answered to a question with an example in English and tagged with `regex`. I know that my answer isn't good enough but I shared it anyway.

Comment: I found this answer helpful for a tool I'm working on using logged exceptions. I've updated the regex for proper optional file and line support. Also, @LasseV.Karlsen Regex is rarely appropriate for localized strings; it's outside the scope of this problem.

Comment: This regex only works if your stack traces are localized in english

Answer (score 2):

**[StackTraceParser](https://github.com/atifaziz/StackTraceParser)**  can parse a stack trace text output (e.g. typically returned by Environment.StackTrace or Exception.StackTrace) back into a sequence of stack trace frames, including the following components:

```
Type
Method
Parameter types and names
File and line information, if present
```

It is available as a [NuGet source package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackTraceParser.Source) that directly embeds into a C# project.

However it requires a few functions to specify and it's usage is not immediately obvious.

```
public static IEnumerable<TFrame> Parse<TToken, TMethod, TParameters, TParameter, TSourceLocation, TFrame>(
    string text,
    Func<int, int, string, TToken> tokenSelector,
    Func<TToken, TToken, TMethod> methodSelector,
    Func<TToken, TToken, TParameter> parameterSelector,
    Func<TToken, IEnumerable<TParameter>, TParameters> parametersSelector,
    Func<TToken, TToken, TSourceLocation> sourceLocationSelector,
    Func<TToken, TMethod, TParameters, TSourceLocation, TFrame> selector)
```

See examples in https://github.com/atifaziz/StackTraceParser and https://bitbucket.org/project-elmah/main/src/2a6b0b5916a6b4913ca5af4c22c4e4fc69f1260d/src/Elmah.AspNet/ErrorDetailPage.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default