# Analysing elmah logs

Tags: .net, asp.net, web, httphandler, elmah

I am using elmah in some of my web application. I am wondering are there any reporting utilities or tools can analyse/scan all the logs and produce a report to show me the common errors in the log. I liked the one at http://demo.l4ndash.com/PageDashboard/Dashboard.aspx but it is for Log4Net and not Elmah.

Comment: Write your own. Group by the error type. Allow for date range searching. A simple stored procedure will do the trick.

Comment: There are also stack trace serializers out there that will allow you to drill down even further into namespaces etc. Ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148167/how-to-split-a-stacktrace-line-into-namespace-class-method-file-and-line-number

Comment: We are trying to decide on a common logging mechanism for at least 8 applications which use different logging mechanisms. We wanted to cut down on creating my own log monitoring and log analysis front end. I like Elmah's approach on minimum code changes to add logging to existing applications.

Comment: God I hate "Write your own" comments, like we've all got several days of free time each week for these menial tasks. They must not have a job...

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [a post on ELMAH's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elmah/XLy_VSwlh9E/QQJa1MBC6QoJ):

> ELMAH permits you to download the entire log as a CSV. Using this
>   option, you have two ways to analyze the data with existing tools. For
>   example:
>
> - Excel for a quick analysis
> - Microsoft Log Parser as a more comprehensive query and analysis tool

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this tool could be of some use: http://code.google.com/p/elmah-loganalyzer/

Comment: Just took this for a spin and it looks very promising - good job Pelle. Are you planning on creating newer versions of it? Or do some sort of maintenance of the tool in the future?

Comment: Thanks @Lasse Christiansen - sw_lasse I haven't touched that code in a while =) but if someone has a good idea for a new feature or find a bug I will absolute continue the work.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer to an old question for any future visitors...

http://elmahr.apphb.com/

"ElmahR = ELMAH + SignalR"

"Real-time error monitoring, made easy"