# How to get StackTrace without Exception in Windows Universal 10 App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I know it was possible to use:

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
```

but that seems to not work anymore, as it needs an Exception-Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Environment.StackTrace. Just remember to be careful with what your logic afterwards is as stacks can change in unpredictable ways. Some discussion here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1420

Answer (score 1):

Check out this discussion on [.NET Core's github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx):
[Where have StackTrace and StackFrame gone?](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1420).

This class isn't there in .NET Core, but there's an open task to implement it: [Implement System.Diagnostics.StackTrace/StackFrame](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1797) - just no one actively working on it yet.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround until .Net Core 2.0 will be available you can parse Environment.StackTrace string as suggested in answeres to [How to split a stacktrace line into namespace, class, method file and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148167/how-to-split-a-stacktrace-line-into-namespace-class-method-file-and-line-numbe/44734351#44734351) -using RegEx or [StackTraceParser](https://github.com/atifaziz/StackTraceParser)