# Extracting parts of a Stacktrace string

Tags: c#, substring, extract, stack-trace

I was wondering is there is a good way of sub stringing parts of a StackTrace string.

Lets say I have a stacktrace showing this:

> at TestApplicationInsightLogging.Controllers.TestController.PostEndpoint(TestPostModel input) in c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestApplicationInsightLogging\TestApplicationInsightLogging\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 35

An I want to extract some information from that stack trace, such as:

- Code-Line:  "Line: 35"
- Controller: "TestController"
- Method: "PostEdnpoint(TestPostModel input)"

I know I can substring by counting letters ans stuff, but I don't thing that is dynamic enough for different kinds of stacktraces.

Comment: https://github.com/atifaziz/StackTraceParser

Comment: `The reason i want to do this is because i have a limited amount of characters to work with.` <= what do you mean by this?

Comment: Looks like some simple regex ... where you find this.that(parameters) and line x

Comment: What is the end goal of doing this? What happens with the information?

Comment: I know it was a bit unnecessary to write that but it just got put down when thinking of it. the reason is that i am logging this information in Application insights analytics and custom properties can only contain up to a 100 characters or something like that. when trying to insert the whole stacktrace it gets cut in half. @Igor

Comment: @BugFinder ok so lets say i write a regex for line number for example. that's a number that would most likely be different depending on what error i get for example. How would you include any number as long as it is related to the "line" so to speak?

Comment: If might be easier to work with individual frames instead of string. If you have instance of `Exception` - do `new StackTrace(exception)` and then explore each frame.

Comment: @john if you cant pull out "line ([0-9])+"  then you need to read up on regex

Comment: @BugFinder Haha you're right about that, i just think i haven't quite yet understood how exactly regex works so to speak. But i'm learning! thats why i'm asking mate! ;)

Comment: @Evk i think you're really on to something there that's a really good tip. didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a stacktrace line into namespace, class, method file and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148167/how-to-split-a-stacktrace-line-into-namespace-class-method-file-and-line-numbe)

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Log Parser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) tool. Add a layout to your logging framework (e.g. [CsvLayout for NLog](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/CsvLayout)) that formats the log as CSV, then you can parse it.